# Two side Printing issue in vb6

Tags: vb6, duplex

Hi guys i am developing a vb6 application to print an ID card for students. I need to print on both sides of the card. I write the code in the way as shown below

```
Printer.Duplex = vbPRDPHorizontal
"Printing front side function"
Printer.NewPage
"Printing backside Function"
Printer.EndDoc
```

While executing the code i getting an error cannot assign a value to printer.Duplex, also can't able to print on both sides

Kindly help me guys to resolve the issue...!